# Unexpected shutdown while resizing partitions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, shutdown

I run Paragon Hard Disk Manager 15 to resize the partitions on my disk: first partition (on which I have Windows 10) and the second (where I put my stuff). The computer was restarted to do the partitioning but after some time it shutdown (perhaps due to discharged batter). When I run computer I got an error message. I run Paragon Hard Disk Manager once again from USB and I showed a message that resizing was interrupted and ask me if I want to continue this job. When I clicked `Yes` it started the resizing process again. This time everything seems to be OK: Windows 10 boot, and I have data on my disk. **How do I know which files are damaged?**

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: @Run5k I did some another tests. I checked all `sfv` files, compared the files on my disk to those on my backup. Almost all was fine, however, I cannot be 100% sure that other files are fine too because they seem to be OK (when run or opened) but it doesn't prove that they are intact.

Comment: Hopefully so.  As I said before, it sounds like your partition management software may have gracefully recovered everything.  Based upon everything you have seen afterwards, I think you can move forward with some peace of mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sounds like your partition management software may have gracefully recovered everything, but to ensure that your operating system is stable I would do the following:

1. Right-click on `Start`
2. Select `Command Prompt (Admin)`
3. Type **sfc /scannow** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The *System File Checker* will run and help verify that your OS files are still undamaged.

Comment: Thanks for this. This way I will have a hint whether at least some files are damaged or not. But how about other file? Sometimes I have `.sfv` files which helps, so I could check other files.

Comment: Verifying the checksums like that could also be beneficial.  If you don't mind me asking, did you have a good backup of your pertinent files & folders before you started the partition resizing?  If so, it may be a good idea to hold onto it for quite some time and perhaps even consider restoring the data on that "stuff" partition.

Comment: I have backup for the most important files. However, I don't have for music or videos.

Comment: For future reference, it really is a "best practice" to have a full backup of your pertinent files and folders before initiating a major OS update, resizing the partitions on your hard drive, etc.  Hopefully someone else can chime in with an additional file integrity utility suggestion.